# Convert Hex to Decimal from signed 2's complement

Tags: arduino-ide

I am reading data from a meter over dlms protocol and I am getting hex values from there. I want to convert that hex string to signed decimal value. For example - ff9d denotes a value of -99 [[reference]](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html).

My hex to decimal code is:

```
unsigned int hexToDec(String hexString)
{
  unsigned int decValue = 0;
  int nextInt;

  for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i++)
  {
    nextInt = int(hexString.charAt(i));
    if (nextInt >= 48 && nextInt <= 57) nextInt = map(nextInt, 48, 57, 0, 9);
    if (nextInt >= 65 && nextInt <= 70) nextInt = map(nextInt, 65, 70, 10, 15);
    if (nextInt >= 97 && nextInt <= 102) nextInt = map(nextInt, 97, 102, 10, 15);
    nextInt = constrain(nextInt, 0, 15);
    decValue = (decValue * 16) + nextInt;
  }
  return decValue;
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to do it in Arduino IDE?

Comment: Have you tried googling something like "C++ convert hex string to int"?

Comment: Yes, I have converted hex string to decimal. But can't figure out the signed part. I can share that code if you want?

Comment: Yes, please share the code. You can edit your question for including it.

Comment: I have edited my question @chrisl

Comment: You do not want to convert the number to decimal: you want to convert it to binary. An `int` is represented in binary. Decimal is used for representing integer literals in the _source code_, but the compiler converts them to binary and, at runtime, every number is in binary.

Comment: Any code snippet you have on how to do this in Arduino @EdgarBonet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example – ff9d denotes a value of -99

The function you wrote returns an *unsigned* integer which, being
unsigned, cannot be negative. The simple fix is to declare it as

```cpp
int hexToDec(String hexString)
```

That should be enough to get it working as expected. Note that the local
variable `decValue` still has to be unsigned, otherwise you would get a
signed overflow, which is *undefined behavoir* (i.e. “forbidden”) in
C++. Returning an unsigned number from a function that is supposed to
return a signed number is perfectly fine: you get an implicit conversion
which is guaranteed to do the right thing.

Now, if I may provide some more feedback about this function:

- Use, if you can, plain C strings (`char *`) instead of `String`
  objects, as the latter are not very friendly to your Arduino's memory.
- Use fixed-length integers (`uint16_t` if your protocol dictates 16-bit
  integers) instead of the generic `int`, otherwise your code will fail
  if you move to a 32-bit platform, such as an ARM-powered Arduino.
- Use character literals (`'0'` instead of `48`) instead of hard-coding
  ASCII code points, as that makes the code more readable.
- Use a simple subtraction (`nextInt - '0'`) instead of the quite
  expensive `map()` function.

Here is my take at it. Note that it has a “classic C” accent you do not
need to replicate. You may prefer using indices to crawl the string.

```cpp
int16_t hex2int(const char *hex)
{
    uint16_t value;  // unsigned to avoid signed overflow
    for (value = 0; *hex; hex++) {
        value <<= 4;
        if (*hex >= '0' && *hex <= '9')
            value |= *hex - '0';
        else if (*hex >= 'A' && *hex <= 'F')
            value |= *hex - 'A' + 10;
        else if (*hex >= 'a' && *hex <= 'f')
            value |= *hex - 'a' + 10;
        else
            break;  // stop at first non-hex digit
    }
    return value;
}
```

Example usage:

```cpp
Serial.println(hex2int("ff9d"));  // prints "-99"
```

---

**Edit**: As revealed by the comments, the whole question is an [XY
problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking help about your misguided *solution* rather
than your actual *problem*. The data you have is not hex: it's binary.
You have a 16-bit signed integer stored in a byte array, most
significant byte first. You figured out you can convert that to an
integer by converting it first to a string representation as
hexadecimal, then converting that representation back to a binary
number. Of course you can do that, but it's an overly complicated and
expensive way of doing something trivial.

The canonical way to recover an integer from a byte array is by
assembling the bytes together using bitwise logic and bit shifts. In
this case:

```cpp
int16_t reactive_power = (uint16_t) data[dataSize - 5] << 8
                       | data[dataSize - 4];
```

Comment: How should I pass ff9d as string in the hex2int function?

Comment: @Prateek: See the example I added.

Comment: I am doing this:
String reacP = String(data[dataSize - 5], HEX) + String(data[dataSize - 4], HEX);
Serial.println(hexToInt(reacP)); **but I am getting the error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int16_t hexToInt(const char*)'**

Comment: @Prateek: Looks to me like you are converting binary data to hex string, only to convert it back to binary. Please edit your question showing how you get the data. Most importantly: what is the data type of `data`?

Comment: That datatype of `data` is unsigned char as in `void ReactivePower(unsigned char data[], int dataSize)`.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding .c_str() in the hex value. Thanks a lot @edgarbonet once again!

Comment: @Prateek: This is a very bad solution. See the amended answer.

Comment: Ohh, is that the case. Let me then check your ammended answer. Just out of curiosity why is using .c_str() a bad idea ?

Comment: @Prateek: Converting to a string in the first place is a bad idea. Representing numbers as strings of ASCII digits is useful for human consumption, but useless in your situation. Your problem is the kind that can be trivially solved by moving a couple of bytes around. Instead, you are taking a very long, memory costly and CPU intensive diversion.

Comment: I realized the mistake @edgarbonet. Your method worked perfectly. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Which mode of DLMS you are you using?

> IEC 61107 or currently IEC 62056-21, was an international standard for a computer protocol to read utility meters. It is designed to operate over any media, including the Internet. A meter sends ASCII (in modes A..D) or HDLC (mode E) data to a nearby hand-held unit (HHU) using a serial port. [IEC 62056](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_62056)

In your question you mentioned:

> hex string

which means a string of hex characters using ASCII (modes A to D).

However, in the comments you mentioned:

> `void ReactivePower(unsigned char data[], int dataSize)`
> `String reacP = String(data[dataSize - 5], HEX) + String(data[dataSize - 4], HEX);`

which means an array of bytes obtained from a stream of bytes using HDLC (mode E).

## ASCII (Modes A to D)

For ASCII (modes A to D), there is a simple transformation to get the digit value from the hex character.

```
              ASCII
 Hex   --------------------                            Digit
 char  Decimal  Hexadecimal    Op1    Low nibble  Op2  Base 10
-----  -------  -----------  -------  ----------  ---  -------
 '0'      48        30        & 0x0F       0              0
 '1'      49        31        & 0x0F       1              1
 '2'      50        32        & 0x0F       2              2
 '3'      51        33        & 0x0F       3              3
 '4'      52        34        & 0x0F       4              4
 '5'      53        35        & 0x0F       5              5
 '6'      54        36        & 0x0F       6              6
 '7'      55        37        & 0x0F       7              7
 '8'      56        38        & 0x0F       8              8
 '9'      57        39        & 0x0F       9              9
 'A'      65        41        & 0x0F       1       +9    10
 'B'      66        42        & 0x0F       2       +9    11
 'C'      67        43        & 0x0F       3       +9    12
 'D'      68        44        & 0x0F       4       +9    13
 'E'      69        45        & 0x0F       5       +9    14
 'F'      70        46        & 0x0F       6       +9    15
 'a'      97        61        & 0x0F       1       +9    10
 'b'      98        62        & 0x0F       2       +9    11
 'c'      99        63        & 0x0F       3       +9    12
 'd'     100        64        & 0x0F       4       +9    13
 'e'     101        65        & 0x0F       5       +9    14
 'f'     102        66        & 0x0F       6       +9    15
```

- For characters '0' to '9', simply `AND` with 0x0F.
- For characters 'A' to 'F' and 'a' to 'f', `AND` with 0x0F and `add` 9.

```cpp
char ch = '1';
byte b = 0;
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
{
  b = ch & 0x0F;
}
else if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f'))
{
  b = (ch & 0x0F) + 9;
}
```

It's also important to know whether the transformation was successful, e.g. the first character could be bad (either a null terminator or non hex character), so this needs to be tested for during the transformation. Also, there are four nibbles in an `int16` so the transformation needs to quit when a maximum of four hex characters have been processed:

```cpp
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  char string[] = "A";
  //char string[] = "Waffle";
  //char string[] = "ff9d";
  int16_t the_int = 0;
  int count = AsciiToInt16(string, the_int);

  Serial.print(string);
  Serial.print(",  ");
  if (count)
  {
    Serial.print("Ok,  ");
    Serial.print(count);
    Serial.print(",  ");
    Serial.println(the_int);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Bad");
  }
}

int AsciiToInt16(const char* ch, int16_t& value)
{
  int count = 0;
  byte nibble = 0;

  // Stop after 4th nibble or null terminator.
  for(int i = 0; i < 4 && ch[i] != 0; i++)
  {
    if (AsciiToNibble(ch[i], nibble))
    {
      value <<= 4;
      value |= nibble;
      count++;
    }
    else
    {
      break;  // Stop after non hex digit.
    }
  }
  return count;
}

bool AsciiToNibble(const char ch, byte& b)
{
  if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
  {
    b = ch & 0x0F;
    return true;
  }
  else if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f'))
  {
    b = (ch & 0x0F) + 9;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**Output**

```
A,  Ok,  1,  10
Waffle,  Bad
ff9d,  Ok,  4,  -99
```

## HDLC (Mode E)

For HDLC (mode E), simply do:

```cpp
void ReactivePower(byte data[], int dataSize)
{
  uint16_t reacP = (data[dataSize - 5] << 8) | data[dataSize - 4];
  Serial.println(dataSize);
  Serial.println(reacP);
}
. . .
  byte data[] = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 8 };
  ReactivePower(data, sizeof(data));
```

**Output**

```
6
773
```